# Get characters of a string (from right)

Tags: python, string

I'm looking for the best way to get a file name of a variable that looks like that:

```
 a = 'this\is\a\path\to\file'
 print a[-4:]
```

I'm trying to get 'file' by just extracting the last four letters with print a[-4:] but the result is:

```
 ile
```

If I make print a[-5:] I get:

```
 ofile
```

I guess python has a problem with the backslash, escaping it did not help. How would you solve this? Would you do it my way or is there a more performant way to get "file" by searching '\' from right to left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\f` is a single character (form-feed) in Python. Try doubling your backslashes:

```
a = 'this\\is\\a\\path\\to\\file'
```

or, equivalently:

```
a = r'this\is\a\path\to\file'
```

After that `print a[-4:]` will print `file`.

Comment: Is there also a method which doesnt change the variable a? something like r'(a)' ... because I cant edit a, I need to work with it unescaped

Comment: @JohnBrown It will be escaped already dont worry, it's only when you manually write it wrong like that it comes out wrong but Python modules will produce the correct result. Also the best way `os.path.splitext`

Comment: I came up with this nvm b = a.replace("\\","")[-4:]

Comment: @JohnBrown why do you **think** you need to do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import os
>>> a = 'A/B'
>>> os.path.normpath(a)
'A\\B'
>>> a = 'A/./B'
>>> os.path.normpath(a)
'A\\B'
>>> a = 'A\B'
>>> os.path.normpath(a)
'A\\B'
>>> a = 'A\\B'
>>> os.path.normpath(a)
'A\\B'
```

Then instead of use [-4:] better practice is to use 'A//B'.split(os.path.sep)[-1] then you are sure you get whole last part of path.
os.path.sep returns separator in current os.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = r'this\is\a\path\to\file'
>>> print a[-4:]
file
```